# Foreman trying to install bootloader on sda vs sdi/sdj software raid

Tags: foreman

I have 35 servers, most of them (~25ish) installed with no problems whatsoever, but the others are giving me grief about not being able to install the bootloader. I'm running Foreman 1.12.3 and CentOS 7.

Looking at the anaconda logs, I'm seeing an error: 
boot loader stage1 target device is sda
boot loader stage2 target device is boot
These lead into an "ERR" reporting that bootloader.write failed: boot loader install failed.

The issue now leads into my question - What am I doing wrong? All these servers are exactly the same, with slots 0 through 7 (sda through sdh) as being data disks and slot 8 and 9 (sdi and sdj) are the OS disks - 480G SSDs. How and where do I direct bootloader to install to sdi or sdj?

I'm using the following files: Kickstart Default, Kickstart Default Finish and Kickstart Default PXELinux.

The only customization I've made is for the Partition Table:

`<%#
kind: ptable
name: Kickstart default
oses:
- CentOS
- Fedora
- RedHat
%>
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part raid.001 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdi --size=2048
part raid.002 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdj --size=2048
part raid.003 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdi --size=51200
part raid.004 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdj --size=51200
part raid.005 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdi --size=204800
part raid.006 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdj --size=204800
part raid.007 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdi --size=2048
part raid.008 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdj --size=2048
part raid.009 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdi --size=51200
part raid.010 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdj --size=51200
part raid.011 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdi --size 102400
part raid.012 --fstype="mdmember" --ondisk=sdj --size 102400
raid swap --device=swap --fstype="swap" --level=RAID1 raid.001 raid.002
raid /home --device=home --fstype="ext4" --level=RAID1 raid.003 raid.004
raid / --device=root --fstype="ext4" --level=RAID1 raid.005 raid.006
raid /boot --device=boot --fstype="ext4" --level=RAID1 raid.007 raid.008
raid /var --device=var --fstype="ext4" --level=RAID1 raid.009 raid.010
raid /var/log --device=log --fstype="ext4" --level=RAID1 raid.011 raid.012`

Comment: Have you considered using UEFI boot instead? It is 2016, after all.

Comment: You can use msdos partitions type instead GPT. Create three partitions: 1 swap, 2 raid for /boot, 3 raid for LVM. Inside LVM create all volumes root, home, var and etc. Be sure that you install boot MBR on sdi and this disk is checked as first boot disk in server BIOS

Comment: The issue turned out to be boot order, which makes no sense whatsoever. Previous boot order:

Network
CDRom
HDD (what equates to the /dev/sdi device)

Changed to:
Network
HDD
CDRom

For whatever reason, this corrected the issue.... makes no sense b/c there is no CDRom. Chocking this up to this equipment being Wiwynn gear (TONS of odd things with this hardware platform!)